# JQuery page load: Active class

Tags: jquery

I have some JQuery that will set a class to active onclick. but when I load the page nothing is "Active" not until I click one of the list items. Is there a way that one can be select upon the page load?

Current JQuery:

```
   $(".setup-nav").on( "click", "li", function() {
    $(".setup-nav li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
   });
```

Comment: Ehhhh... Yes... Set one as active...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add active to your the HTML item.

```
<ul class="setup-nav">
    <li class="active">This is your fist active item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
</ul>
```

And, to prevent keeping the last change by soft reloading the page which could be happened by some browsers, just use this:

```
$(".setup-nav li.active").trigger('click');
```

Comment: This works until I reload the page and it stays on the same page but goes back to active on the wrong list item.

Comment: Well of course it does. You will need to determine which page you are on to dynamically select which page is active on load. 

Thats an entirely different question. In regards to what you asked, this is the answer. You will need to post your code, what framework you're using etc.. in order to answer an active on page load question.

Comment: @CameronBass, I think you are using Firefox. that's why it's happening. I am going to update this answer.

Comment: Thank you @Mojtaba!

Answer (score 1):

You can use of `localStorage`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     var active = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("activeLi"));
     $(".setup-nav li:nth-child(" + active + ")").addClass("active");

     $(".setup-nav").on("click","li",function(){

         $("li").removeClass("active");

         $(this).addClass("active");

         localStorage.setItem("activeLi",$(this).index() + 1);

     })
 })
```

Comment: @Epik , Check my Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to give code with some changes to achieve :)

```js
 $(".setup-nav li").click(function() {
    $(".setup-nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
   });
```

```css
ul.setup-nav li{
  background: #FFF;
  color:#666;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
.setup-nav .active{
background: #666;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="setup-nav">
  <li class="active">ABC</li>
  <li class="">ABC</li>
  <li class="">ABC</li>
  
  </ul>
```